# order data.frame based on 2 columns and vector of variables

Tags: r, variables, dataframe, multiple-columns

I need to order a `data.frame` based on 2 columns and a given vector of variables.

Here n example of my df:

```
df = data.frame(A = rnorm(45),
                B = rep(c('a', 'b', 'c'), each= 5, times = 3),
                C = rep(c(10, 20, 30), each = 15))
```

I need to change the order of `col B` from `c('a', 'b', 'c')` to `c('c', 'a', 'b')` while still keeping `col C` fixed to the 3 variables groups.

Here the first 30 rows of my desired output:

```
  A          B  C
 -0.11451485 c 10
 -0.11860742 c 10
  0.08156183 c 10
  1.11850750 c 10
 -0.79072556 c 10
  1.24141030 a 10
  0.88538811 a 10
 -1.35548712 a 10
  0.05723677 a 10
  0.14660464 a 10
 -0.28587107 b 10
  0.59452832 b 10
  1.00163605 b 10
  1.15892322 b 10
 -1.41771696 b 10
 -2.05743546 c 20
 -1.22835358 c 20
  1.50060736 c 20
 -0.14956114 c 20
 -1.13126592 c 20
  1.08571256 a 20
 -1.04991699 a 20
 -1.50655996 a 20
 -0.63675392 a 20
 -0.26485423 a 20
  0.30509657 b 20
  0.85471772 b 20
 -0.54064736 b 20
  0.24578056 b 20
  0.14917900 b 20
```

Any help will be really appreciated,
  thanks

Comment: Please use `set.seed` while generating random numbers. Also you don't really need 45 rows, you could reduce the example to 10 rows to make it easier to compare results.

Comment: thanks. what's the reason of using set.seed? I always wondered it..

Comment: Making sure any randomization is reproducible. `set.seed()` means you can repeatedly generate a same set of pseudo-random numbers and so your result is repeatable if you apply the same seed

Comment: @aaaaa `set.seed` makes sure functions like `rnorm` or `sample` will return the same result for reproducibility.

Comment: wow! that's brilliant! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to change the level of the factor column. After that, we can use `arrange` from the `dplyr` package to sort multiple columns. Notice that in your original post, sorting column A is not a requirement. I just add column A to the `arrange` call to show it is easy to include more than two columns to the `arrange` function.

```
library(dplyr)

df2 <- df %>%
  # Change the level of the factor
  mutate(B = factor(B, levels = c("c", "a", "b"))) %>%
  # Arrange the column
  arrange(C, B, A)
df2
#              A B  C
# 1  -2.39317699 c 10
# 2  -1.48901928 c 10
# 3  -0.42562766 c 10
# 4   0.03383395 c 10
# 5   0.66362189 c 10
# 6  -0.65324997 a 10
# 7  -0.59408686 a 10
# 8   0.37012883 a 10
# 9   0.53238177 a 10
# 10  3.03972004 a 10
# 11 -2.03192274 b 10
# 12 -1.05138447 b 10
# 13 -0.80795342 b 10
# 14  1.74526091 b 10
# 15  2.07681466 b 10
# 16 -1.90573715 c 20
# 17 -0.72626244 c 20
# 18 -0.48017481 c 20
# 19 -0.42995920 c 20
# 20  0.17729002 c 20
# 21 -0.62947278 a 20
# 22 -0.40038152 a 20
# 23 -0.23368555 a 20
# 24  0.44218806 a 20
# 25  1.58561071 a 20
# 26 -0.66270426 b 20
# 27 -0.50256255 b 20
# 28 -0.19890974 b 20
# 29  0.26562533 b 20
# 30  1.84093124 b 20
# 31 -0.93702848 c 30
# 32  0.10804529 c 30
# 33  0.25758608 c 30
# 34  1.33084399 c 30
# 35  1.67204875 c 30
# 36 -1.88922564 a 30
# 37 -1.74551938 a 30
# 38 -1.32215854 a 30
# 39 -0.43743607 a 30
# 40  1.07554466 a 30
# 41 -0.38154167 b 30
# 42  0.53823057 b 30
# 43  0.83401316 b 30
# 44  1.04418363 b 30
# 45  2.45985490 b 30
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first use `factor()` to order your `B` factor by levels you define; With that, you can now order your data frame by `B` to get your desired output.

Generating some data:

```
set.seed(10)
df = data.frame(A = rnorm(45),
                B = rep(c('a', 'b', 'c'), each= 5, times = 3),
                C = rep(c(10, 20, 30), each = 15))
```

And using `levels` to re-level your factor before ordering the data frame:

```
df$B <- factor(df$B,levels = c('c', 'a', 'b'))
df$B <- sort(df$B, decreasing = F)
df <- df[order(df$C), ]
```

Output (first 20 rows):

```
1.0177950   c   10  
0.75578151  c   10  
-0.23823356 c   10  
0.98744470  c   10  
0.74139013  c   10  
0.01874617  a   10  
-0.18425254 a   10
-1.37133055 a   10  
-0.59916772 a   10  
0.29454513  a   10  
0.38979430  b   10  
-1.20807618 b   10  
-0.36367602 b   10  
-1.62667268 b   10  
-0.25647839 b   10  
-0.37366156 c   20  
-0.68755543 c   20  
-0.87215883 c   20  
-0.10176101 c   20  
-0.25378053 c   20
```

Comment: Your output is different than the OP's desired output. You may want to sort column C first.

Comment: You're right, OP also wanted `C` variable to be sorted. Fixed that and thanks for catching it

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer. the order of the variables is still not what I am looking for.

Comment: You can do `df <- df[order(df$C, df$B), ]` to sort multiple columns.